# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.hxtt.sql.by.bu()Lcom/hxtt/global/a0;

Tags: java, hibernate, ms-access-2010

I am trying to work with MS ACCESS and Hibernate. And I caught such exception:

```
    Exception in Application init method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown   Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.hxtt.sql.by.bu()Lcom/hxtt/global/a0;
at com.hxtt.sql.a.getTypeInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo.extractTypeInfo(TypeInfo.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at service.Menu.init(Menu.java:59)
... 4 more
 Exception running application service.Menu
```

My configuration file is shown bellow:

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
     <property      name="connection.driver_class">com.hxtt.sql.access.AccessDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:access:///d:/hw71.accdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">com.hxtt.support.hibernate.HxttAccessDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="domain.Notebook"/>
    <mapping class="domain.CPU"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Memory"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Vendor"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Store"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Sales"/>
</session-factory>
```

Exception appears when I am trying to build a SessionFactory. Please help me, or advise something.